# adding opacity's of the PhoneAccentBrush to a Silverlight toolbox pie chart

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

i am working on a windows phone application and i am using the pie chart - i am relatively new to the silverlight control toolbox.

i want to make my pie chart use different opacity's of the `PhoneAccentBrush` as its colour pallete. (ie if the accent colour is green then i use the green and then a 0.8,0.6,0.4,0.2 opacity of the colour as my pie charts pallete)

i have tried a few things, but none of them worked - has anyone accomplished this and if so how?

thanks in advance
Doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took what i had (it was very similar to rhooligan's post) and massaged it with some solid brushes that i added to the app.xaml:

in the xaml view page:

```
 <charting:Chart x:Name="chartMyChart" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}" Style="{StaticResource ChartStyle1}" LegendStyle="{StaticResource PieLegendStyle1}">
                    <charting:Chart.Palette>
                        <visualizationToolkit:ResourceDictionaryCollection>
                            <ResourceDictionary>
                                <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PieChartColour1}"  />
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PieChartColour1}" />
                                </Style>
                            </ResourceDictionary>
                            <ResourceDictionary>
                                <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PieChartColour2}" />
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PieChartColour2}" />
                                </Style>
                            </ResourceDictionary>
                            <ResourceDictionary>
                                <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PieChartColour3}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PieChartColour3}" />
                                </Style>
                            </ResourceDictionary>
                            <ResourceDictionary>
                                <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PieChartColour4}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PieChartColour4}" />
                                </Style>
                            </ResourceDictionary>
                            <ResourceDictionary>
                                <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PieChartColour5}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PieChartColour5}" />
                                </Style>
                            </ResourceDictionary>
                        </visualizationToolkit:ResourceDictionaryCollection>
                    </charting:Chart.Palette>
                    <charting:PieSeries 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                        DependentValuePath="NumberOfReferrals" 
                        IndependentValuePath="Sources" 
                        Background="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}" 
                        Style="{StaticResource PieSeriesStyle1}" 
                        LegendItemStyle="{StaticResource LegendItemStyleShown}"
                        Margin="0" 
                         />
                </charting:Chart>
```

and then in my app.xaml:

```
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PieChartColour1" Opacity="1" Color="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PieChartColour2" Opacity="0.8" Color="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PieChartColour3" Opacity="0.6"  Color="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PieChartColour4" Opacity="0.4"  Color="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PieChartColour5" Opacity="0.2"  Color="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}" />
```

YAY!

Answer (score 1):

What did you try and why don't you think it's working?

I am not too familiar with the WP7 sdk but I did do some work with the Silverlight toolkit Pie chart a few weeks back and defining pallet colors was something like this:

```
     <visualizationToolkit:ResourceDictionaryCollection x:Key="ChartColorCollection">
        <!-- PIECHART DATA POINT COLORS -->
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <PhoneAccentBrush x:Key="AccentBrush />
            <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource PieDataPointStyle1}" TargetType="chartingToolkit:PieDataPoint">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource AccentBrush}"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <PhoneAccentBrush x:Key="AccentBrush />
            <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource PieDataPointStyle1}" TargetType="chartingToolkit:PieDataPoint">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource AccentBrush}"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <PhoneAccentBrush x:Key="AccentBrush />
            <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource PieDataPointStyle1}" TargetType="chartingToolkit:PieDataPoint">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource AccentBrush}"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>

        <!-- etc -->
```

I did something similar to what you describe with different shades of one color (so each color pallet entry would have a separate ResourceDictionary). In my implementation I was using RadialGradientBrush, but the concept should be the same.

Comment: In Your example all the colours will be the same, or am I missing something?